# How to get files ( Through Directory.GetFile() ) on the basis of DateTime

Tags: c#

I am getting a issue in my application i want to get all the files from folder on the basis of DateTime .is it possible with Directory.GetFile() or any other inbuilt function through C#

Thanks
Shashank

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "on the basis of DateTime"?

Comment: Do you mean get the files by the oldest first, or something like that?

Comment: Yes Bali- i want to get only yesterday files which is running inside a window service

Comment: is that work for you ???

Comment: Yes Parnay Thank you for your Suggestion and Answer

Comment: @Damboo - welcome i m hoping for upvote on each answer.......

Comment: Hii All.I m facing one more issue with this ..in all your's code firstly i get all files and after that we filter all those file on the basis of creation time ... i want to get only files on the basis of creation time because we have more than 20,000 of files which comes daily in inbox folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access all files created yesterday, do something like this in Linq having set up your min/max values desired:

Replace `CreationTime` with `LastWriteTime` if you want to see file modifications rather than creation:

```
var targetDirectory = "Put your dir here";
var minDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
var maxDate = DateTime.Today.AddSeconds(-1);

try
{
    var dir = new Directory(targetDirectory);
    foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles().Where(f => f.CreationTime >= minDate 
                                                && f.CreationTime <= maxDate))
    {
        // Do something with file.
        Console.WriteLine("File : {0}", file.FullName);
    }
}
catch( Exception e )
{
    // Handle access exceptions.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Linq solution**

```
string startFolder = @"c:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\";
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileQuery =
            from file in fileList
            where (file.CreationTime <= maxdate//replac eyour date here
                   && file.CreationTime >= mindate)//replac eyour date here

            orderby file.CreationTime 
            select file;
```

---

You can check file time like this

```
string fileName = @"C:\MyPath\MyFile.txt"; 
    if (File.Exists(fileName)) 
    {
        label_CreationTime.Text = 
                 File.GetCreationTime(fileName).ToString(); 
        label_LastAccess.Text = 
                 File.GetLastAccessTime(fileName).ToString(); 
        label_LastWrite.Text = 
                 File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName).ToString(); 
    }
```

so for check each file in your directly you need to do something like this

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
foreach(string fileName in filePaths )
{
          Console.Writeln(fileName );
          Console.Writeln(File.GetCreationTime(fileName).ToString()); 
          Console.Writeln(File.GetLastAccessTime(fileName).ToString()); 
          Console.Writeln(File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName).ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: Hii parnav ..I m facing one more issue with this ..in all your's code and other code firstly i get all files and after that we filter all those file on the basis of creation time  ... i want to get only files on the basis of creation time because we have more than 20,000 of files which comes daily in inbox folder

Comment: @Damboo - hey you can do one thing is create multiple thread and divid the 1000 file per each thread and than process rest of the code...

Answer (score 1):

A very good example using the System.IO.FileSystemInfo.CreationTime can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Get FileInfo and check creation/modified date is an option I can think of

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    var d = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
    var filesInfo d.GetFiles().OrderBy(x => x.LastAccessTime);
```

Or you can query date time also

```
   var filesInfo = d.GetFiles().Where(x=>x.LastAccessTime > datetTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) and filter the `FileInfo` objects by the `LastWriteTime` property, for example:

```
var minimumDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\MyFolder");
var files = directory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(f => f.LastWriteTime >= minimumDate);
```

Note that this might throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.